# How to transfer value from textbox of one jsp page to textbox of another jsp page?

Tags: jsp, java-ee-6

i want to transfer value entered in one textbox of one jsp page to another textbox in another jsp page.

Please help me..

Comment: it is a plain JSP or you are using any sort of framework?

Comment: Are you using simple Jsp, Servlet or with any framework?

Comment: @ umesh and subodh: I am using struts2 framework with simple JSP...

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear how you're interacting between the two JSPs. I'll assume that you've a `<form>` in the first JSP which submits to the second JSP. In that case, all submitted values are available as request parameters the usual way. You can access request parameters by `${param}` in EL.

So, this should do in `first.jsp`:

```
<form action="second.jsp">
    <input type="text" name="foo" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

It'll be available by `${param.foo}` in `second.jsp`:

```
<%@taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
...

<form ...>
    <input type="text" name="bar" value="${fn:escapeXml(param.foo)}" />
    ...
</form>
```

*(the `fn:escapeXml()` is mandatory to prevent XSS attack holes)*

Answer (score 0):

In plain JSP you can use JSP built-in `request` object to get field value.
Use:

```
<%=request.getParameter("FIELD_NAME_IN_SECOND_JSP");%>
```

If you are using Struts, you can first send the data to the server (e.g. struts value). Set any class property with this JSP field value and get this property value in the second JSP page using struts tag lib.